# mongodb group with some field and push all back

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have following collection

```
_id:60b8c9294af8f15198249e5b
title:"abcd"
note:"abcdfregh"
date:2021-06-03T12:16:28.598+00:00
User_id:2
createdAt:2021-06-03T12:20:57.261+00:00
updatedAt:2021-06-03T12:20:57.261+00:00
Journal_id:15
__v:0
```

I am trying to $group with month and year in a date and $push all fields

Query:

```
Upload.aggregate([
        { $match : { User_id : Number(user_id)}},
        { $group : { 
            _id : { month: { $month : "$date" },year: {$year : "$date"}},
        details : {$push : {"title" :"$title","note" : "$note"}}
    }},
            ]),
```

But am getting a output like this:

```
[
  { _id: 'abcd', details: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { _id: 'aabghk\tinjcwmdsoi', details: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

I am new to mongodb and working hard to understand this error;

the desired output i need is:

Expected output:

```
[
  { _id: 'abcd', details: [ {title:"title here", note: "note here"}, {title:"title here", note: "note here"} ] },
  { _id: 'aabghk\tinjcwmdsoi', details: [   {title:"title here", note: "note here"} ] }
]
```

Comment: Your sample code is correct and works just fine on MongoPlayground

Comment: then i am getting such an output :-(

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rqZs5HGhbt2         You sure you have shared the right query?  Please share your code on the driver side.

Comment: let me know how can i do that?

Comment: @hhharsha36 code on the driver side? Can you please explain?

Comment: By driver, I meant the code in your backend. `node.js` `mongoose`. Another possibility for the result is that if the value itself is an object instead of a string.

Comment: @hhharsha36 can u please help me to remove the square brackets in the output json .

Comment: Provide the exact input and output you are trying it get. Give me the sample document in question. We shall sort it out.